# how to select first child or sibling with jquery when building a slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following markup

```
<div class="content chapters current-tab">
    <div class="right">
        <div id="chapters-container-29" style="">
        <div id="chapters-container-10" style="display: none">
   </div>
</div>`
```

And this jquery code:

```
var direction = $(this).data('direction'),
    visibleContainer = $('div[id^=chapters-container-]:visible'),
    container = $('div[id^=chapters-container-]');

    if (direction === 'next') {
            if (visibleContainer.is(':last-child')) { 
                visibleContainer.hide(); 
                container.first().show();
            }

            visibleContainer.hide();
            visibleContainer.next().show();
        } else {               
            if (visibleContainer.is(':first-child')) {
                visibleContainer.hide();
                container.last().show();
            }

            visibleContainer.hide();
            visibleContainer.prev().show();
        }`
```

This is for a slider....when I am at the end `visibleContainer.is('last-child')` it is working fine, but when I am @start and click previous it is not working. `visibleContainer.is(':first-child')` not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [this](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)?

Anyway, this code will work:

```
if (direction === 'next') {
    if (visibleContainer.is(':last-child')) { 
        visibleContainer.hide(); 
        container.first().show();
    } else {
        visibleContainer.hide();
        visibleContainer.next().show();
    }
} else {               
    if (visibleContainer.is(':first-child')) {
        visibleContainer.hide();
        container.last().show();
    } else {
        visibleContainer.hide();
        visibleContainer.prev().show();
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? because from your code I see that the first panel should remain always visible if you press 'prev' button and you have only 2 html divs to rotate.

Comment: Maybe you want to rewrite the whole script adding an **else** statement after `if (visibleContainer.is(':first-child')) { ... }` and also for the other case

Comment: @MariusIlie: I've edited your answer , because you were talking about **:first**, and your code was still using **:first-child**.

Comment: I asked if he tried using :first, not that I'd recommend using it. :first-child is the right way to do it. Now the code doesn't work any more so I have to change it back...